# How to add placeholder for the existing Woocommerce product text fields

Tags: wordpress

I am a bit new to WordPress... When I want to create a new product with woo-commerce, the long description area and a short description are not really explicit. Can someone tell me how I can add a place holder to these text fields. The Product name already has a placeholder. Just want to do same for long description and a short description

I tried locating the code but do not really know what to add and in which file, but think functions.php file could be better

I will like to achieve [something like this.](http://prntscr.com/nyie5d)

Comment: Hi, depends on theme that your are using. What the name? or you develop custom themes?

Comment: Am using the custom WordPress theme with woocommerce but there is a possibility that I will change the theme.